# using := gives unused error but using = don't in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, compiler-errors, mgo, go-gin

I have piece of code in which I get error when I use `:=` but when I use `=` it compiles properly. What I learned is that `:=` only requires only atleast one variable to be defined, others need not be defined, but considering this code is it a bug in Go?

**Uncompilable code:**

**Error: services/db_service.go:16: Session declared and not used**

```
package services

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "log"
)

const DB = "mmdb_dev"

var Session *mgo.Session

func InitMongo() bool {
    url := "mongodb://localhost"
    log.Println("Establishing MongoDB connection...")
    //var err error
    Session, err := mgo.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot connect to MongoDB!")
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func GetNewSession() mgo.Session {
    return *Session.Copy()
}
```

**Compiled code**

```
package services

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "log"
)

const DB = "mmdb_dev"

var Session *mgo.Session

func InitMongo() bool {
    url := "mongodb://localhost"
    log.Println("Establishing MongoDB connection...")
    var err error
    Session, err = mgo.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot connect to MongoDB!")
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func GetNewSession() mgo.Session {
    return *Session.Copy()
}
```

The change is

```
Session, err := mgo.Dial(url)
```

to

```
var err error
Session, err = mgo.Dial(url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator `:=` is used for [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). It declares and initializes the variable.

In your first example, you have declared `Session` variable in global scope and in `main` function you've declared a new variable having same name in the main scope (as you have used `:=` operator). Therefore, the `Session` variable declared in the global scope is unused and hence the error.

In your second example, you have assigned global variable a value using assignment operator `=` and hence it is not declaring a new `Session` variable but assigning a value to existing global variable.

Please find an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/3p1o7ji3yI) showing difference between global and local variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are shadowing your Session variable. Your first example is creating a new Session variable and now it won't compile b/c the other is declared but unused.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `:=` the variable definition is within the function. i.e. the ***scope*** of the variable changed, from global to local. And you're not using variable locally, hence the compilation error.